# opening file from variable and whitespace

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the whitespaces of my output and I've tried words = [x.strip(' ') for x in words] but it didn't work at all.

also, I'm trying to have it to open more than the file data1.txt. I've tried to assign it to my input but it never recognizing it because of the brackets it displays when it's a string i think not sure if it's the reason.

```
Exemple of output:
anana :  12
Orange:24
Patate: 21


def ligne(texte):
    with open(texte) as ouvrir:
        lecture = ouvrir.readlines()
        words = [x.split(":")[0].strip() for x in [line.strip() for line in lecture]]
        words = [x for x in words if len(x) > 1]
        return lecture
    return "Le fichier {} n'existe pas.".format(texte)

def main():
    while True:
        entree = sys.argv[1:]
        choix = str(entree)
        texte = "data2.txt"
        if texte in choix:
            message4 = sorted(ligne(texte))
            for i in message4:
                print(i)
            break
        else:
            print("Il faut préciser le nom du fichier à traiter")
            break
```

Comment: text.split() may help, it splits a str line into list of words using whitespace as a delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You returned `return lecture`, but you changed `words`, also you can change code to `split` and `strip` your input line, like this:

```
def ligne(texte):
    with open(texte) as ouvrir:
        lecture = ouvrir.readlines()
        words = [':'.join([x.strip() for x in line.split(':')]) for line in lecture]
        words = [x for x in words if len(x) > 1]
        return words
    return "Le fichier {} n'existe pas.".format(texte)
```

If you want to call more than one file, you can do this:

```
def main():
    entree = sys.argv[1:]
    for item in entree:
        message4 = sorted(ligne(item))
        for i in message4:
            print(i)
```

And run your code whit files as arguments:

```
python your_code.py first_file.txt secend_file.txt ...
```

Comment: my words lookds like this patate : 21 i dont see : 21 when i do this

Comment: please give me a simple input and your expected output

Comment: i've edited my question. And also my input is the file name that i want to open. In this case it is data1.txt but i would be able to enter data2.txt or data3.txt also

Comment: can you please take a look at my second question?

Comment: , I'm trying to have it to open more than the file data1.txt. I've tried to assign it to my input but it never recognizing it because of the brackets it displays when it's a string i think not sure if it's the reason.

Comment: @Isen I changed it

Comment: i am sorry i havent been clear on that one. i want to be able to open only 1 file at a time, but with a different name than data1.txt, i could be data2.txt instead. Will your solution work for this too?

Comment: @Isen check it ;) https://gist.github.com/RaminNietzsche/e6833c80cbc2db5bd849cb2effa15341

Comment: i don't understand how it can work if i say texte = data1.txt

Comment: It's ok i found how! i jsut had to specify this line         texte = choix.strip("[']") insteadn and now i can open the file i want. Thanks a lot for all your answer you've been a great help i understand better now